# Updating Formik Initial Values from Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, infinite-loop, formik

My app is using formik &  redux I've encountered a challenge when it comes to updating initial values from Redux without affecting other **filled** input fields in the form.

Currently, I'm using the enableReinitialize option with Formik, which successfully updates the initial values based on changes in the Redux store. However, this approach also leads to unintended behavior where other filled input fields get cleared upon each update.

```
const valuesFromRedux = {
  name: "Agnes",
  age: "44",
  sports: [{ name: "Volleyball", ranking: 3 }],
};

const initialValues = { 
  name: "", 
  age: "", 
  sports: valuesFromRedux, 
  newSport: { name: "", ranking: "" };
}

const handleSubmit = () => {
  // do something here
};

const MainComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Stack>
      {" "}
      <Formik initialValues={initialValues} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {({ values }) => (
          <Form>
            <Stack>
              
              <ComponentA /> // form that displays name & age

              <ComponentB values={values.sports} /> // form that displays sports

              <ComponentC /> // form that adds a new sport(an object added to
              // valuesFromRedux.sports) has a button that dispatches this action

              <Button type="submit">Submit</Button> // button that dispatches name &
              age to redux (sports not dispatched as it is addedfrom component C)

            </Stack>
          </Form>
        )}{" "}
      </Formik>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Although the below method is achieving the desired outcome of updating the values based on the Redux store, I've encountered significant performance issues in the application, leading to slow responsiveness.

I am also getting "Too many re-renders. The layout is unstable. TextareaAutosize limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" error message.

Here's how I've implemented the method in the <ComponentB/>:

```
import useFormikContext from "formik";

const ComponentB = ({values})  => {

const valuesFromRedux = useSelector(state => state.formValues.sports);

const formik = useFormikContext()

useEffect(() => {
    if (valuesFromRedux !== values) {
    console.log("Effect ran");
    formik.setFieldValue("sports", valuesFromRedux);
    }
 }, []);

// jsx here
}
```